# Cannot update Ubuntu 20.04 due to unresolvable dependencies

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I haven't used my Ubuntu installation in a while and I just turned it on and am getting this strange error when I try to install the latest round of updates:

**Package dependencies cannot be resolved**

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
Transaction failed: Package dependencies cannot be resolved
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

grub-efi-amd64-signed: Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.31) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.11 is to be installed
```

[image: Here's a picture]

It's a bit incomprehensible to me. Should I be installing `grub2-common` manually? Because that doesn't work either:

```sh
(base) ####@#####science-machine:~$ sudo apt-get install -y grub2-common.
[sudo] password for ####: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grub2-common.
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'grub2-common.'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'grub2-common.'
```

Here are the updates to be installed:

[image: Updates]

What should I do? Should I just forget about it and never install the offending package(s)?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Would you add the  output of `apt-cache policy grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common`  .By the way, the output for manual install, mistyped the package  name `grub2-common.`  there was a dot in the end.

Comment: @user.dz oops! Did not notice that. I no longer have this problem; my updates installed without issue today. I would have otherwise run the command you recommended to me. Thank you regardless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo apt upgrade`

This will attempt to:

1. update the package list
2. autoremove unnecessary packages
3. fix any broken installations and packages
4. upgrade all packages that can be upgraded

Comment: ```apt full-upgrade``` may also help

Comment: Thank you. I ended up forgetting about it and for some reason, today, it no longer has this problem. If this problem shows back up, though, I will try your solution.